# Do different parts of your body have different fast twitch / slow twitch muscle composition?

Tags: muscle

Would someone have a different fast/slow twitch muscle ratio in their chest versus their legs?

Comment: This is a simple “yes” question. Are you looking for anything more than a single word answer? If so, please specify by asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short yes, the percentage of slow/fast fibres will vary with muscle group. Pectoralis major tends to be about 60% fast-twitch fibres. "Legs" is a bit of a generalisation - your soleus, in common with other postural muscles, is predominantly slow-twitch fibres, other leg muscles contain more fast-twitch fibres (taken from [this study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/123895/)):

- Soleus 70% slow-twitch
- Vastus intermedius 47%
- Gastrocnemius 50%
- Vastus lateralis 32%